# Why getting connection refused with elasticsearch 8 and springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to elasticsearch 8 from my springboot 3 project floowing this [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration). But getting `connection refused` error without much details.
Here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com....elastic")
public class ElasticConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("192.168.19.23:9200")
                .usingSsl()
                .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .withBasicAuth("elastic", "abc")
                .build();
        return clientConfiguration;
    }
}
```

I have my SSL certificate in my jdk. The project runs properly but when it tries to save data on elasticsearch, it gets this error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:540)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.doIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.save(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.lambda$save$5(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.executeAndRefresh(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:344)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.save(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:172)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy131.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy131.save(Unknown Source)
    at com...ServiceImpl.sendToElastic(ServiceImpl.java:171)
    at com...ServiceImpl.getIdAndSend(ServiceImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:930)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:962)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.lambda$doIndex$6(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:538)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

I have double checked my url, port and credentials. How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In springboot 3 just creating `ClientConfiguration` bean is not enough, the configuration class needs to extend the class `ElasticsearchConfiguration` as well.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com....elastic")
public class ElasticConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("192.168.19.23:9200")
                .usingSsl()
                .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .withBasicAuth("elastic", "abc")
                .build();
        return clientConfiguration;
    }
}
```

With this configuration `ElasticsearchOperations`, `ElasticsearchClient` and `RestClient` can be autowired as well.

**Edit (P.J.Meisch):** This is documented as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.restclient